# Git - reorder branch commits

Tags: git, rebase

I have the following problem that I need to resolve with GIT.

I have the following:

```
+----------+                                            +----------+
| Branch-0 | --> commit0, commit1, commit2, commit3 --> | Branch-2 | --> commit4
+----------+                                            +----------+

+----------+
| Branch-1 | --> commit5
+----------+
```

I would like to change it to:

```
+----------+
| Branch-0 | --> commit0
+----------+

+----------+                                            +----------+
| Branch-1 | --> commit5, commit1, commit2, commit3 --> | Branch-2 | --> commit4
+----------+                                            +----------+
```

I think I need to use `git rebase`, but not sure.

Will the following work?

```
git checkout Branch-0
git rebase Branch-1
git checkout Branch-1
git rebase Branch-0
git push
```

Comment: Yes, you need to use `git rebase`. Do you have a specific question about it?

Comment: @mkrieger1, thanks for the reply.  Yes, how do I write the `rebase` command for this example? (sorry for my ignorance)

Comment: This is too broad, and the answer involves several steps with different git commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think cherry-pick would be a better approach here.

For branch-1 you can do this:

```
git cherry-pick branch0~3..branc0
```

for brahcn-0 you would need to reset

```
git reset HEAD~3 --hard
```

branch 2 you would probably need to recreate

```
git checkout branch-0
git checkout -b branch-2-tmp
git cherry-pick branch-2
git branch -D branch-2
git branch -m branch-2-tmp branch-2
```